# Move lightbox2 caption to the right and image to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox2

`lightbox2` is exactly what I want, and have been using for a while. But I'm trying to customize it and running up against the limit of my javascript.

Ideally, I would like to have the image on the left (`max-width: 570px;`) and the caption on the right (`max-width: 270px;`) so that it's not hidden beneath the fold.

I've moved the image number and close button to the top thanks to some other solutions here, which is great. However, there doesn't seem to be anything about re-positioning the caption, and I can't figure out how to get it to be anywhere except below the image.

Thanks!

Comment: Imagination has not limits, but still better if you could provide some code in here.

Comment: I'm not sure if or how code would be useful; it's just the standard lightbox2 code. And I can't insert images into my post, nor can I add new lines, so I can't even provide an ascii drawing of what I'm going for. It's just the caption to the right of the image instead of below.